# Parallelizing a for loop using 2 CPUs

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm running a for loop a large amount of times so the process takes almost two and a half hours as is to complete in Jupyter Notebooks. I'm hoping to use two cores to speed up the process but I don't know how to implement this and all my google searches have left me confused. Before, when I've wanted to use two cores I use n_jobs=2 in my machine learning function but here I'm not doing any ML, just a for loop. Here is my code below:

```
## imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing 
import time
import h5py
import time
import requests

## here is where I retrieve my data
baseUrl = 'http://www.tng-project.org/api/'
headers = {"api-key":"f3c97208f4981e63b57bb02c7135912b"}

def get(path, params=None):
    # make HTTP GET request to path
    r = requests.get(path, params=params, headers=headers)

    # raise exception if response code is not HTTP SUCCESS (200)
    r.raise_for_status()

    if r.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
        return r.json() # parse json responses automatically
    return r

r = get(baseUrl)

url_z1 = "http://www.tng-project.org/api/TNG100-1/snapshots/50/subhalos/?limit=10000&offset=0"
subhalos_z1 = get(url_z1) ## uploading my data to subhalos_z1

sub_z1 = [] ## array that contains subhalo information 
tstart = time.time()

len_sub = 10000 ## how many subhalos I want to get the information for

## for loop that retreives the data from 10000 specific subhalos 
for i in range(len_sub):
    sub_z1.append(get(subhalos_z1['results'][i]['url']))
    print(i)

print("Elapsed Time: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start))
```

The for loop above is what I'm looking to optimize, but I don't know where to start in terms of how. Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at Pandarallel package, it does exactly what you want to do: https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel

Comment: I'm installing the library and looking over this now. To implement it should I put my for loop in a function and then run the res = df.apply(func, axis=1) on it? I'm lost on the implementation part of this. I'm not a very adept coder and I have little formal education so I don't really understand functions or parallelization, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Here is the I ended up using:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import math
tstart = time.time()

def func2(sub):
    sub.append(get(subhalos_z0['results'][i]['url']))
    print(i)
    return (sub)
    
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(func2)(sub_z0) for i in range(len_sub))
print("Elapsed Time: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start))
```

For 10 iterations using 2 cores about halved my time. Super useful! Here is a link to the website that helped me out
https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/parallel-for-loops-python/